# How to make white-space: pre-wrap; justify text?

Tags: html, css

I have text within pre tags styled like this:

```
 <pre style="white-space: pre-wrap; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">
        ${htmlText} 
 </pre>
```

Justify text won't work within `white-space: pre-wrap;`. But if the text is not `white-space: pre-wrap;`, then the text white space is deleted. I need the text white space to remain and still be able to justify text.

I've also tried `white-space: pre;` with `overflow-wrap: break-word`. This works, but it splits the words when wrapping text. I need justify to work without splitting/breaking words.

How do you make `text-align: justify;` work with `white-space: pre-wrap;`? Or how do you make `white-space: pre;` while wrapping text in a way that doesn't break words up?

Comment: Consider posting more details about the problem. Maybe there's a solution that doesn't involve the `white-space` property or `<pre>` tag.

Comment: I added to the question another potential solution if there's a way to wrap text without breaking words.

Answer (score 3):

`white-space: pre-wrap;` has no affect on `text-align: justify;` here is an example

```css
.a
{
white-space: pre-wrap;
text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<pre class="a">
  <p>This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph.This is a paragraph</p>
 </pre>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. It's a widespread issue that I haven't found an answer for yet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's no fix for this. The closest thing I could do is set `white-space: normal` and give every p tag the css property `text-indent: 30px;`.

This will justify text and will add an indent to the beginning of every paragraph. But it will also delete all whitespace more than one whitespace. This works for me for now because I was most interested in adding extra whitespace to the beginning of paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works: `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
.a {
white-space: pre-line;
text-align: left;
```

}

In my case, this did the work.
I could manage multiline text and text is justified left